# Harvesting multiple Slicers [Power BI]

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

For a scorecard, I need to weigh some categories based on importance.  Said weights must be selectable from a filter based on their category (categories might have different weights).

I created a table with the weights with the percentages to multiply against and created the below:

CAT3 Selection

```
cat3 Selection =
IF (
    SUM ( Query1[CAT3 Error] ) = BLANK (),
    BLANK (),
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'Weighted Percents'[CAT3 Weight] ),
        VALUES ( 'Weighted Percents'[CAT3 Weight] ),
        0
    )
)
```

CAT4 Selection

```
cat4 Selection =
IF (
    SUM ( Query1[CAT4 Error] ) = BLANK (),
    BLANK (),
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'Weighted Percents'[CAT4 Weight] ),
        VALUES ( 'Weighted Percents'[CAT4 Weight] ),
        0
    )
)
```

cat3 Weighted Scenario

```
( [cat3 Selection] * 1 ) * SUM ( Query1[cat3 Error] )
```

cat4 Weighted Scenario

```
( [cat4 Selection] * 1 ) * SUM ( Query1[cat4 Error] )
```

My problem is this:  When I select a slicer, it works, but it also automatically selects the same value on the other slicer.  If I edit the interactions between the two slicers, I get a value of 0 in the data unless they are the same.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Does the `Weighted Percents` table have a row for each CAT3 and CAT4 weight combination? If not, that's your problem. Having two slicers on the same table doesn't work well if you expect them to be independent.

Comment: Hi, yes, they do.  I did try different tables but got the same results.  Would having the results on separate tables as well maybe fix this or is it a value() issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather convoluted way of harvesting slicers. A more standard way to write things would be like

```
cat3 weighted =
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Weighted Percents'[CAT3 Weight] ) * SUM ( Query1[cat3 Error] )

cat4 weighted =
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Weighted Percents'[CAT4 Weight] ) * SUM ( Query1[cat4 Error] )
```

If this simplified construction still has the same problem, then I would recommend using independent tables for your slicer selections rather than having just the one.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to remove the relationship of the duplicated weight tables and use multiple tables